# ImportError: No module named 'numpy' in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip

I am a newbie in Python world. I have to run a code that uses matplotlib in the python code. I am using Python 3.4 (32 bit) in Windows. I use PyDev for development and running the python script. I installed matplotlib by

```
pip install matplotlib
```

When I tried to run the code again it asks for 'numpy'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\workspace\KMS\readpsds.py", line 14, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 179, in <module>
from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 32, in <module>
import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

When I try to install numpy by

```
pip install numpy
```

it shows the following error in command line

```
Command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Rsh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip_build_Rsh\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Rsh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-t3a6a8l1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Rsh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Rsh\numpyStoring debug log for failure in C:\Users\Rsh\pip\pip.log
```

Please help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: [Use these Windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) to install numpy and matplotlib on Windows as opposed to using pip, it's easier that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of using scientific packages on Windows (numpy, matplotlib) I recommend you to use conda:

http://conda.io

It installs binaries so you won't see any more compiler errors. Plus you can always resort to pip if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Install Anaconda, and run the python.exe in the directory in which Anaconda is installed. If you're using sublime, you can build your system in this directory.

To build a build system, do this:
Tools -> Build System -> New Build System 
Then Copy the following code in the poped up window and save it.

```
{
"cmd": ["YOUR_PATH_TO_ANACONDA/python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

Notice that you should replace YOUR_PATH_TO_ANACONDA by your anaconda path.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

Comment: It was for Windows not Linux

Comment: @sagittarius Oops sry I didn't notice the question was asking for Windows ;P